# Cannot get data updates on NotifyPropertyChanged collection

Tags: inotifypropertychanged, windows-phone-7.1

I'm building a Mango app that writes data to a SqlCe database; I have a `ListBox` bound to a `DataSource` that must show items when they are added to the database, but when I add/update data I cannot get updates and they are only shown when I reload the page.
Here are some snippets:

```cs
public class TimeTrackerViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyPropertyChanging
{
    private List<TimeItems> _timeItems;
    public List<TimeItems> TimeItems
    {
        get { return _timeItems; }
        set
        {
            NotifyPropertyChanging("TimeItems");
            _timeItems = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("TimeItems");
        }
    }

    public void LoadCollectionsFromDatabase()
    {

        // Specify the query for all to-do items in the database.
        var times = from t in db.Times
                    select new TimeItems
                    {
                        DtIn = t.DtIn,
                        DtOut = t.DtOut,
                        Id = t.Id
                    };


        // Query the database and load all to-do items.
        TimeItems = new List<TimeItems>(times);
    }
.....
.....
}
```

When I add data to the Times table I don't see db updates to the listBox bound to the `TimeItems` collection.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `TimeItems` an [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx)